# How to make maven project to see dependencies in my local repository?

Tags: maven, java-ee-7, maven-dependency

I have been facing difficulty with adding dependencies to maven war project .Everytime ,when i try to add dependency in my pom.xml, i don't see java ee 7 api in pom.xml dependencies tab.After i copied from maven repository dependency code to pom.xml source tab,then my project goes fine.
But when i create another new project , then i try to add dependency in pom.xml dependencies tab and i don't see any api.So, i have to copy dependency code from maven repository and add to my pom.xml again.How can i get rid of this?

Comment: what do u mean by "have to copy dependency code from maven repository and add to my pom.xml "? what code? your pom.xml should contain all required dependencies anyway

Comment: <dependency><groupId>....</groupId><artifactId>..</artifactId><dependency> // those tags.